# str_len = struct.unpack('q', len_bytes)[0]

Tags: python, nlp, deep-learning

I'm learning text summary. Can you tell me what's meaning of this code ?

```
with open(f, 'rb') as reader:
          while True:
            len_bytes = reader.read(8)
            if not len_bytes: break
            str_len = struct.unpack('q', len_bytes)[0]
            example_str = struct.unpack('%ds' % str_len, reader.read(str_len))[0]
            e = example_pb2.Example.FromString(example_str)
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Note: The question has been answered as you are trying to learn. Ideally, this question should be closed and tagged as "Off-Topic"!**

As far as I know this is from the tensorflow text summarization example. You might want to look into the code for a better explanation.

The binary file contains data in the  format. The `str_len` extracts the  part and determines the length of the blob. The `example_str` is of length `str_len` and is extracted next.

```
with open(f, 'rb') as reader:                  # opens the file in binary mode.
          while True:
            len_bytes = reader.read(8)         # reads 8 characters
            if not len_bytes: break            # keep reading the file till EOF
            str_len = struct.unpack('q', len_bytes)[0]    #Unpack the data as an 'integer'(due to format 'q'). This is the length of the string
            example_str = struct.unpack('%ds' % str_len, reader.read(str_len))[0] # Unpacks the data as a 'string' of length 'str_len'
            e = example_pb2.Example.FromString(example_str)
```